# get a list of all classes that extend a base class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a baseclass:

```
class BaseModel {
}
```

and all my models extend from it:

```
class User extends BaseModel {
}

class Book extends BaseModel {
}
```

Now I would need a list of all models extending the BaseModel:

```
let modelCollection = {
    User,
    Book
}
```

So I can later create an instance by only knowing the constructor name:

```
let model = new modelCollection['User']()
```

Might seems weird but I need this because I want to create instances on the server that are passed by the client. I need to do it this way because it is not possible to serialize a constructor function that I could pass from the client to the server.
So my request could then look like this:

```
axios.post('/save', { modelName: 'User', modelProps: { name: 'Jon' } })
```

I know that I could just create different endpoints, but I need to do it with just one.

Comment: Can you explain why you must only use a single endpoint?